# Open file manager error android

Tags: android, file, upload

Hi there all developers:
I am using this code snippet

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);`
```

---

There exists a file manager, but its giving a messege<< No apps can perform this action. Why?? Can anyone tell me?
I have also tried without Intent.ACTION_PICK

Answer (score 0):

Please put my code.
it is working.

*** CODE ***

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

intent.setType("file/*");

startActivity(intent);

Comment: But how can i get my file on activity result ?
you are starting activity directly,, hence there will be no result